# Prevent access to single post types

Tags: redirect

Say that I want to make a post type called 'press' and it is mostly concerned with linking a title with a PDF document of a press clipping.  I want to show all of these as an archive... so something like site.com/press but i don't want any single post template pages.  so no site.com/press/article1 or site.com/press/article2. other than not including a link in my archive template (which just obscures it but doesn't negate their existence or prevent access to the single posts) how can i prevent a visitor from inadvertently accessing the single posts.  how could i re-direct them back to the /press archive?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### The fast way

In your .htaccess add a rule

```
RedirectMatch Permanent ^/press/.+ /press/
```

### Plugin way

Hook into `template_redirect` and redirect all requests to a single entry:

```php
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wpse_45164_redirect_press' );

function wpse_45164_redirect_press()
{
    if ( ! is_singular( 'press' ) )
        return;

    wp_redirect( get_post_type_archive_link( 'press' ), 301 );
    exit;
}
```

*(Caveat: not tested)*

Comment: @toscho is there an argument which does this when registering a custom post type? Or is redirecting the only way to prevent access to a single custom post type page?

Comment: @Anagio The alternative is: make the post type not public, register an endpoint to show the archive. But the you have to fiddle with the query (pagination, plugins don’t hook in when they should etc.). The solution I gave in my answer is the most pragmatic approach I could come up with.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to redirecting users would be to make it so this page isn't generated to begin with. Setting your post type to `'public' => false, 'publicly_queryable' => true` will create a non-public post type. Then you can build a custom page template to act as the archive, with a custom query in the page template.

See the [`register_post_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments) function for more info.

Comment: I don't believe that your answer is correct. When `publicly_queryable` is set to `true`, both the Archive and Singles will properly render.

Comment: By default `public`is set to `false`. This answer is not correct. From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#public): 

'true' - Implies exclude_from_search: false, publicly_queryable: true, show_in_nav_menus: true, and show_ui:true. The built-in types attachment, page, and post are similar to this.

'false' - Implies exclude_from_search: true, publicly_queryable: false, show_in_nav_menus: false, and show_ui: false.